# Windows 10 reassigns drive letters on reboot

Tags: windows-10, reboot, disk-management, drive-letter

Through being forced to for a software program my company uses, I recently switched from Windows 7 to Windows 10.  Now, every time I reboot, my computer decides to assign letters E, F, G, and H with generic icons for my removable flash drive slots which I have always had as W, X, Y, and Z, along with custom names and icons for them (through a registry entry).  When I reassign drive E into W, it then immediately associates with the custom name "micro/mini/SD" and my icon for the SD card reader.  F is X for "CompactFlash", G is Y for "SmartMedia / xD", and H is Z for "Memory Stick".  Through several reboots, at least the wrong assignment has been consistent.

I would like to set something (like a batch file, because that's about the limit of my ability to understand and adjust if needed) to run on startup to reassign those drive letters as specified.  I have seen similar search results suggesting "net use __" but I'm fairly certain that won't work for my use-case, because I believe it was mapping a network drive.  I think I saw "set vol" somewhere, but when I looked up the "vol" command/modifier/whatever, it seemed like it would just display a volume's name.  And this is not something I would want to just test on my own, knowing I could screw things up.

Any hints would be great, or a definitive statement that this isn't something a batch file could do, or a pointer to what language/commands could work..  Any help is appreciated. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 is here to stay and drive letter usage will remain and (to the best of my knowledge) in the future with feature updates.

So it will be best in the longer term for you to adapt and use the Windows 10 drive letter assignments.